# How to inherit sys.path of Conda environment in child process

Tags: python, bash, conda, sys.path

I have a conda environment that has some python packages installed, and I need access to the `sys.path` when I run a program in that environment.

In addition to having the current environment activated in shell, I have a bash script to run that program that reinitiates conda and reactivates the environment:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

source ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh

conda activate myenv

/opt/MyProgram/Program
```

However when I use the python interpreter in `MyProgram`, the `sys.path` is completely overwritten with whatever is it in the `PYTHONPATH` and some additional paths that are set from the program itself. I'm almost sure this exact method has worked for me before so I'm not sure what I did different this time around, but I would prefer not to manually set `PYTHONPATH` as I didn't have to do that before.

In this case `MyProgram` is a stand-alone GUI graphics software that has its own Python interpreter that runs in a section of GUI on startup.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Assuming "*stand-alone...software*" means binary, how does it invoke Python? What do you mean by it has its own Python interpreter? E.g., was this some PyInstaller build? It seems feasible to me that changes need to be made within this program's code, rather than changing something in the shell that invokes it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by how does it invoke Python, this is a 3rd party application, think of something like Blender. It has it's own python.exe, site-packages, pip, etc. Also just to note, I have done this before successfully without changing any source code or anything even remotely as complicated as that, it worked for me before by calling the program using the snippet above.

Comment: If internally it is using Python's `-E`, `-s`, or `-I` flags when it calls Python, then that would be actively preventing use of `PYTHONPATH` and/or user-level `site-packages`. However, if you've had success with this program before, then possibly you have a Python version mismatch. Ensure that `my_env` has the same Python version (major+minor, e.g., 3.8) as the application's internal Python.